# Problem with expansion of \@ifnextchar inside tabular environment

Tags: tables, conditionals, expansion

I'd like to define a macro that expands to `\hline` and `\cline` inside the tabular environment depending on the next character:

```
\documentclass{standalone}           

\makeatletter
\def\mycline[#1]{\cline{#1}}
\def\myline{\@ifnextchar[{\mycline}{\hline}}      % Does not work. Either misplaced \noalign or \omit 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
a1 & a2 \\
\myline
b1 & b2 \\
\myline[1-2] 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this results in a misplaced `\noalign` or `\omit` (or both). It seems that `\@ifnextchar` doesn't get fully expanded in time. Any idea?

Comment: Due to how scanning for `\noalign` works, an unexpandable command (here `\futurelet` used by `\@ifnextchar`) starts a new alignment cell and it's too late for a line to be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to how scanning for `\noalign` works, an unexpandable command (here `\futurelet` used by `\@ifnextchar`) starts a new alignment cell and it's too late for a line to be inserted.

You have to do the scanning for the optional argument inside a `\noalign` group:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\def\myline{%
  \noalign\bgroup
  \@ifnextchar[%
    {\aftergroup\mycline\egroup}%
    {\aftergroup\hline\egroup}%
}
\def\mycline[#1]{\cline{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
a1 & a2 \\
\myline
b1 & b2 \\
\myline[1-1]
c1 & c2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why are you looking for trouble? `;-)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm playing around with the radio table format from Orgmode (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/A-LaTeX-example.html#A-LaTeX-example). It's fun ;-)